# simple messaging app without server

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am new to iOS development and started a tutorial on a simple messaging app using Parse as the server. The way they have it coded, the app queries parse every time a message is sent(to save the message) but seeing as Parse only allows 30 req/sec under its FREE plan how would one go about making a messaging app? Is it standard convention to save data to the server for each message? It just doesnt seem practical to have a substantial user base on an app that can only query the serve 30 times a second.

The question simplified is: what is the standard convention for the relationship with servers for a simple messaging apps? Does the app save each message to a server or is there a work around using push notifications? (But even with push notifications the app would have to be opened to receive them, at least thats from my limited understanding of pushes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is not** practical to have a substantial user base for a messaging app with only 30 queries per second. Parse is running a business. They give you 30 API req/sec so that you can try out their service and see how it works. But if you are designing an app for a significant user base, you will surely have to pay, as you are expecting Parse to run the servers for you.

With that out of the way, it would be normal for a (typical) messaging app to make at least one API request per *sent* message to the server. The server is responsible for accepting, routing, holding, and delivering messages. It would also be normal for that sent message to result in a push notification, and an API request from the client app to retrieve the message. The general workflow would be:

1. User sends message
2. App uploads message to server
3. Server determines where message is headed
4. Server sends push notification to recipient
5. Recipient app queries server for pending message(s)
6. Recipient app displays message(s) for recipient user

That's two API requests and a push notification for each sent message.

Beyond that, depending on your messaging service design, the server may also store all messages so that later, on a different device, a user can open the app and it will download the history, so as to appear synchronized.

Now, surely there are ways to reduce the number of server API requests. Your app could batch messages locally, your server could batch push notifications, and your clients could batch queries (or you could do all three). All of these options could help dramatically reduce the number of server API requests you pay for, but they will also reduce the responsiveness and user experience of your messaging service.

You could also design a sophisticated peer-to-peer communication system (like Skype was in the past) removing servers from the messaging flow. However, you would have to design complicated authentication and verification systems, complicated routing systems, complicated storage systems, etc. A **lot** of work. And even if you did, I don't know if Apple would allow it on the App Store. A lot of time, work, and uncertainty to avoid paying the small cost for a server.

Regarding push notifications: Push notifications are sent from a server to a recipient client app. Your iPhone cannot push notification another iPhone. There will always be a server in the middle. Your app does not need to be open to receive a push notification. iOS will receive it, and then deliver it to your app. If your app is closed, iOS will (partly) open it in the background to deliver the message.